# My car will start right up no sounds but will die after 30 mins of idling

Tags: engine

It's a 1998 saab 900 s 2.3 L car was maintenanced regularly until 2019 which it sat until I bought it a couple months ago. The car is in great condition. When I start the car it turns on perfectly no sounds no anything, after about half an hour the car will die and wont start again until left for awhile. Then it will start up perfectly and die again. I got the fuel pump checked and it's not the pump.. I'm not sure what else it could be. Please help.

Comment: Do you leave it idling for 30 minutes? Why? If you want to warm it up it is better to drive.

Comment: A failing crankshaft sensor could fault when it gets hot.

Comment: I run into these symptoms a lot for failing engine control modules. Considering the age and the fact it was fine then sat a year and is now doing this its possibly just some bad caps in it. Its pretty common repair job I see come in around those years across many makes/models.

Comment: Coils breaking down once warm?  Can you get the OBD codes read?